# Trying to upload a image to server using laravel and also resize it

Tags: php, laravel-4

Here is the code I am trying to do:

```
$image        = Input::file('image');
$organization = Organization::find(Auth::user()->organization->id);
$filename     = $organization->id . '.jpg';

$path = public_path('storage/org_logos/' . $filename);
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(217, 113)->save($path);

$organization->logo = 'storage/org_logos/' . $filename;
$organization->save();
```

So I get the image from it being uploaded by the user, and I store the filename etc...

I am getting the error:
Can't write image data to path (absolute_path/storage/org_logos/04147.jpg)

Anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you set the permissions of `storage` to 777 recursively?

Comment: my permissions werent 777 for org_logos cause I just created however I did make it 777 for drwxrwxrwx  2 myuser myuser  4096 Feb  5 16:31 org_logos/

it but still seeing the same error... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions of 'storage' and 'org_logos' folders. Permissions should be 777

Comment: my permissions werent 777 for org_logos cause I just created however I did make it 777 for drwxrwxrwx  2 myuser myuser  4096 Feb  5 16:31 org_logos/

it but still seeing the same error... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers I got it to work it was combination of not having permissions and also I was using public_path instead of storage_path for the helper.

Switching it to storage_path('org_logos/' . $filename); worked!

Thanks for the help